# Spring Batch decider not executing

Tags: spring-batch

I have a simple batch job with a decider. The decider implementation only adds the error to a list and then returns the original FlowExecutionStatus. The parser is failing and exiting instead of failing and executing the decision step. Why? (I know ErrorHandler is not being called because the output never includes the logger ouput "*in decider asdf*". Also what is the best way to debug the xml? Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

```
<batch:job id="testDecider">
    <batch:step id="testme" next="testerDecider">
        <batch:tasklet>
            <batch:chunk reader="csvSLHistoryFileReader"
                processor="stationSendStatsCalculator" skip-limit="5" commit-interval="10"
                writer="noOpWriter">
                <batch:skippable-exception-classes>
                    <batch:include class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileParseException"/>
                </batch:skippable-exception-classes>
            </batch:chunk>
        </batch:tasklet>
    </batch:step>
    <!-- this commit interval can be 1 because all the input from previous step will be completed and this step will 
    iterate through the created to-from list -->
    <batch:step id="doTallies">
        <batch:tasklet>
            <batch:chunk reader="stationSendCountsListReader"
                processor="passThrough" commit-interval="100000"
                writer="stationSubtotalsFileWriter">
            </batch:chunk>
        </batch:tasklet>
    </batch:step>
    <batch:step id="tryTesterInput">
        <batch:tasklet>
            <batch:chunk reader="csvSSHistoryFileReader"
                processor="stationSendStatsCalculator" skip-limit="5" commit-interval="10"
                writer="noOpWriter">
                <batch:skippable-exception-classes>
                    <batch:include class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileParseException"/>
                </batch:skippable-exception-classes>
            </batch:chunk>
        </batch:tasklet>
    </batch:step>
    <batch:decision id="testerDecider" decider="errorHandler">
        <batch:next on="FAILED" to="tryTesterInput"/>
        <batch:next on="*" to="doTallies"/>
    </batch:decision>
</batch:job>
```

Error Handler:

```
public class ErrorHandler implements JobExecutionDecider {
@Resource List<String> errorsList;
private final Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(getClass());
private String badInput = "none";
private int newErrors = 0;

/* (non-Javadoc)
 * @see org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.JobExecutionDecider#decide(org.springframework.batch.core.JobExecution, org.springframework.batch.core.StepExecution)
 */
@Override
public FlowExecutionStatus decide(JobExecution jobExecution,
        StepExecution stepExecution) {
    logger.info("in decider asdf");
    if (stepExecution.getExitStatus().getExitCode().equals("ERRORS")){
        if (errorsList.size() > 0){
            newErrors = errorsList.size();
            logger.info("Errors encountered in previous step: "+ errorsList.size());
            return new FlowExecutionStatus ("FAILED");
        }
    }   
    return new FlowExecutionStatus(jobExecution.getStatus().toString());
}
```

}

The exception:

```html
    12:47:37,180 [main] INFO  ProcessStatisticsTasklet  - constructor...
12:47:37,529 [main] INFO  RequestsListReader  - constructing requestsListReader
12:47:37,662 [main] INFO  SimpleJobLauncher  - Job: [FlowJob:     [name=testDecider]] launched with the following parameters: [{csvHistoryFileName=input/ssXactHistory.csv, csvStationsProfileName=input/bostonStationsProfile.csv, RequestGenerationFileName=input/bostonRequestGeneration.xlsx}]
12:47:37,680 [main] INFO  SimpleStepHandler  - Executing step: [testme]
12:47:37,759 [main] ERROR AbstractStep  - Encountered an error executing step testme in job testDecider
org.springframework.batch.core.step.skip.SkipLimitExceededException: Skip limit of '5' exceeded
 at org.springframework.batch.core.step.skip.LimitCheckingItemSkipPolicy.shouldSkip(LimitCheckingItemSkipPolicy.java:133)
 at org.springframework.batch.core.step.skip.ExceptionClassifierSkipPolicy.shouldSkip(ExceptionClassifierSkipPolicy.java:70)
 at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.FaultTolerantChunkProvider.shouldSkip(FaultTolerantChunkProvider.java:134)
 at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.FaultTolerantChunkProvider.read(FaultTolerantChunkProvider.java:91)
 at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProvider$1.doInIteration(SimpleChunkProvider.java:114)
 at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.getNextResult(RepeatTemplate.java:368)
 at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.executeInternal(RepeatTemplate.java:215)
 at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.iterate(RepeatTemplate.java:144)
 at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProvider.provide(SimpleChunkProvider.java:108)
 at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.ChunkOrientedTasklet.execute(ChunkOrientedTasklet.java:69)
 at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$ChunkTransactionCallback.doInTransaction(TaskletStep.java:395)
 at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:130)
 at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$2.doInChunkContext(TaskletStep.java:267)
 at org.springframework.batch.core.scope.context.StepContextRepeatCallback.doInIteration(StepContextRepeatCallback.java:77)
 at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.getNextResult(RepeatTemplate.java:368)
 at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.executeInternal(RepeatTemplate.java:215)
 at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.iterate(RepeatTemplate.java:144)
 at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep.doExecute(TaskletStep.java:253)
 at org.springframework.batch.core.step.AbstractStep.execute(AbstractStep.java:195)
 at org.springframework.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler.handleStep(SimpleStepHandler.java:141)
 at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.JobFlowExecutor.executeStep(JobFlowExecutor.java:64)
 at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.state.StepState.handle(StepState.java:60)
 at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.resume(SimpleFlow.java:151)
 at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.start(SimpleFlow.java:130)
 at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.FlowJob.doExecute(FlowJob.java:135)
 at org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob.execute(AbstractJob.java:301)
 at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher$1.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:134)
 at org.springframework.core.task.SyncTaskExecutor.execute(SyncTaskExecutor.java:48)
 at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:127)
 at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.CommandLineJobRunner.start(CommandLineJobRunner.java:351)
 at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.CommandLineJobRunner.main(CommandLineJobRunner.java:577)
Caused by: org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileParseException: Parsing error at line: 6 in resource=[URL [file:input/ssXactHistory.csv]], input=[12/07/14 19:58:54,12/07/14 19:58:54,12/07/14 20:00:02,0,0,12,54,67,19,0,1,0,1,,,,[157] 20:00:02 Empty Zone:16  Station:165 YK L/D ===> Interzone:110 ===> Zone:5  Station:53 NS 5 W ,Station:165 YK L/D,Station:53 NS 5 W,None,None,,,Zone:16 ,Zone:5 ,]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The exception is pretty clear in that the skip-limit of 5 has been hit which will cause the step to fail.  When using the `<step ... next="someStep">` notation for the next state, the next state is only executed if the step completes successfully (which it has not in your case).  Because of that, your decision won't execute.  Instead, you need to use the longer hand version of defining where to go:

```
<step>
 ...
  <next on="FAILED" to="testerDecider"/>
</step>
```

Comment: Thank-you very much for the great support! This worked (of course).